# Methods available across an app?

Tags: java, android, methods

I'm 100% sure this is going to be one of those newbie questions, but here it goes...

Is there a way I can write a method in one activity and be able to access it from the others?

Example:
I have six activites in my app, each with it's own menu.xml because the options available for each need to be different, and I have these menus & menuitems set up as shown:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.calculator_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuItem_calculator_Help:
            helpDialogGo();
            return true;
        case R.id.menuItem_calculator_Settings:
            //settingsActivityGo();
            return true;
        case R.id.menuItem_calculator_Share:
            shareGo();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in Action Bar clicked; go home
            Intent uptohome = new Intent(this, Main.class);
            uptohome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(uptohome);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

The an example of one of these methods is:

```
private void helpDialogGo() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "help", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alt_bld.setMessage("Sorry, no help has been written since this application is still in development. This is a prerelease version.")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Cool", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // Action for 'Yes' Button
        dialog.cancel();
        }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //  Action for 'NO' Button
        dialog.cancel();
        }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        // Title for AlertDialog
        alert.setTitle("Pixel Help");
        // Icon for AlertDialog
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.question);
        alert.show();
    }
```

So is there a way to have this custom method shared among all the activities and run it when the button is pressed in each of them, as to avoid having large amounts of code replicated across my app?

And if so, are there any potholes that I may hit? (Some of the menu items are going to bring up dialogs, others will take the user to a new activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have similar menuitems in every activity? i.e. same number of items but different behaviour? If yes... 
How about creating a BaseActivity which overrides onCreateOptionsMenu and  onOptionsItemSelected() methods.. (As you have given in the above example). All your activities should inherit from this BaseActivity and then override the menu handling methods. eg. helpDialogGo() will go to the new class.

so the BaseActivity will have onCreateOptionsMenu and  onOptionsItemSelected() methods. Plus all the menuItem actions (i.e. helpDialogGo() etc) as empty methods. The inherited classes will overide menuItem Actions.

If the menuitems are not similar in each activity, you are better off creating menu for each activity.

**EDIT:**

Not sure what you expect more. I thought I made it clear. Let me try again.

Class `BaseActivity` extends `Activity`.

```
BaseActivity extends Activity {

    // Copy your onCreateOptionsMenu() and onOptionsItemSelected() methods here

    protected void helpDialogGo() { }

    // ... other methods
}
```

Class `MyActivity1` extends `BaseActivity`.

```
MyActivity1 extends BaseActivity {

    // Copy your helpDialogGo() code in full here and then make
    // any specific changes to menu behaviour based on activity.

}
```

Class `MyActivity2` extends `BaseActivity`

```
MyActivity2 extends BaseActivity {
    // Copy your helpDialogGo() code in full here and then make
    // any specific changes to menu behaviour based on activity.
}
```

Comment: This is actually fairly common way to do this. And it is not Android specific but more relevant to best practices for class design.

Comment: Ok. Can you elaborate a little more before I start.

Comment: @rabs83 not sure what you expect more.. I thought I made it clear.. let me try again.. 
Class BaseActivity extends Activity { 
// copy your onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected() methods here
protected void helpDialogGo() { }
// ... other methods
} 
Class MyActivity1 extends BaseActivity {

//copy your helpDialogGo code in full here and then make any specific changes to menu behaviour based on activity}
Class MyActivity2 extends BaseActivity {
//copy your helpDialogGo code in full here and then make any specific changes to menu behaviour based on activity
}

Comment: @GSree Thanks so much. I'll play around with that later when I'm back at my desk.

Comment: I don't fully agree with your last comment. It is in violation with the DRY principle and does not really do what the OP asked for. He wanted to avoid copy-pasting of code. Ideally you should add the code of the helper method to the `BaseActivity` so it is ready to use in the derived activities.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean Understand your concern. However, you are making an assumption that there are more than one activity which will share that functionality. If there are more one activity uses the same menuaction, then it belongs to BaseActivity (and dont even override anywhere). However, if each activity shares the menu items but not actions, it is better to override in subclasses. Then again.. if the actions are not same (menu item and menu action), repeating may be a better choice. Agree!

Answer (score 1):

One way, of course, is to created some custom classes that encapsulate your desired functionality - and use those within your activities.  It's a better abstraction than placing the implementation directly in the Activity(s) itself (all things being equal, and based on what you described so far).

Any time you find yourself duplicating an implmentation that's a flag reminding you this is a good place to roll that code into its own class - usually.

Comment: Okay, so it _is_ a good idea? Now how do I go about it? One new class with each method in it or one with all of them in it? I know it's a lot to ask; but sample code would be great. Thanks for your help!